# Append a list until a size limit is reached then start a new list

Tags: python-3.x, list, while-loop, nlp

I have a list of texts and I need to split each text in multiple chunks each shorter than a limit of 5000 bytes.

The idea is to split each text in sentences and then add them back one by one until the limit of 5000 is reached.

This is how far I got (see the code). I'm def doing something wrong. But I spent too much time debugging it so will really appreciate a pair of fresh eyes. Thanks!

To test it you need can use any text larger than 10k bytes.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

def split_text(text, limit):
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    def get_chunk(sentences, limit):
        results = []
        counter = 0
        while counter < limit:
            for s in sentences:
                counter += len(s.encode('utf-8'))
                results.append(s)
                sentences.remove(s)
        return results, sentences

    out = []
    while len(' '.join(sentences).encode('utf-8')) > limit:
        results, sentences = get_chunk(sentences, limit)
        out.append(results)
    else:
        out.append(sentences)
    text_out = [' '.join(sentences) for sentences in out]
    return text_out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
size = 0
l = [] #list of sentences
ll = [] #list of lists 
for s in sent_tokenize(text):
    if size + len(s.encode()) <= 5000:
        l.append(s)
        size += len(s.encode()) + 1 # +1 for space 
    else:
        size = 0
        ll.append(l.copy())
        l.clear()

# save the remainder (if any):
if l:
    ll.append(l.copy())
```

we can check that the chunks are all of length <= 5000 bytes:

```
for l in ll:
    print(len(' '.join(l).encode()))
#4983
#4987
#4781
#4943
# .. etc ..
#
```

Comment: I run your suggestion on the same text with 10235 bytes. The output is two chunks - one 4994 and another 4997. The rest is lost (two last sentences of the original text).

Comment: I added two lines of code at the end to save the remainder. It should work now :) Let me know

Comment: Does exactly what I need. Cool! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove items from the `sentences` list while iterating over it; this has the effect of skipping every second item:

```
>>> l = list(range(5))
>>> for x in l:
...     print(x)
...     l.remove(x)
... 
0
2
4
```

Also in `get_chunk` you're iterating over the full list of sentences.

Instead you could use a [`peekable`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.peekable) iterator for sentences:

```
sentences = peekable(sent_tokenize(text))
```

Then the code for `get_chunk` would  be:

```
def get_chunk(sentences, limit):
    results = []
    counter = len(sentences.peek().encode('utf-8'))
    while counter < limit:
        results.append(next(sentences))
        try:
            counter += len(sentences.peek().encode('utf-8')) + 1
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return results
```

Then you can simply `map` that function repeatedly over the iterator until `peek` raises a `StopIteration`:

```
from functools import partial
import itertools as it

out = map(partial(get_chunk, limit=limit), it.repeat(sentences))
```

Comment: I run your code using a text of 10235 bytes. The result was two chunks - one 5131
and another 5103 bytes (one byte is missing because of white space).

Comment: @aviss You're right, in order to stay below the limit we need to switch the `if` condition and the `append` in `get_chunk`. Please see my updated answer.